# Java enum as spring component - Spring allows this but does not inject members that are declared in the enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, enums

I have a question on the behavior when making a java enum as a spring managed component with an `@Component` annotation. I see that spring allows this (`@Component` after all has `@Target(value=TYPE)`) but when i try to inject an enum member with `@Autowired` it does not get injected. Below is sample code snippet for our purpose (`ObjectMapper` does not get injected below),

```
@Component
public enum AssetTypeEnum {

    SWITCH {
        @Override
        public AssetDataCollectionRequest getDataCollectionRequestObjectFromJsonString(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SwitchAssetDataCollectionRequest.class);
        }
    }, GIGE {
        @Override
        public AssetDataCollectionRequest getDataCollectionRequestObjectFromJsonString(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, GigePortAssetCollectionRequest.class);
        }
    }, NAMESERVER {
        @Override
        public AssetDataCollectionRequest getDataCollectionRequestObjectFromJsonString(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AssetDataCollectionRequest.class);
        }
    };

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    public abstract AssetDataCollectionRequest getDataCollectionRequestObjectFromJsonString(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException;// {
    //  return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AssetDataCollectionRequest.class);
    //}
    
    public AssetDataCollectionResponse getDataCollectionResponeObjectFromJsonString(String jsonString) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AssetDataCollectionResponse.class);
    }
```

Also in the above if i un-comment the commented lines above & change the method from an abstract method, i get below weird error on app start up,

```
rest-sample-service - [WARN ] 03:57:49.385 [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assetTypeEnum' defined in file [/BOOT-INF/classes/com/**/**/sampleservice/common/AssetTypeEnum.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
rest-sample-service - [INFO ] 03:57:49.574 [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener   - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
rest-sample-service - [ERROR] 03:57:50.776 [main] org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.**.**.sampleservice.common.AssetTypeEnum required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle, and I hope you learn useful information from it, but _don't do this in an application_. Among other things, enums are implicitly static, which brings in all of the shared-state problems that DI is intended to solve.

Comment: Hi @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i am just curious, it happened out of accident when i was refactoring code then i realized spring had not complained...then i tried adding a member to inject which is when it failed injecting...so i thought i can ask in SO..will update this thread on what i learn...